# How to plot 'group by' in python

Tags: python

I have a csv that contains warehouses, dates and quantities (stock). I'm trying to plot the quantities by date for each warehouse (a separate plot by warehouse). I'm a beginner in Python, I've tried looking around but I can't find anything that would solve my problem.
Here's what the table looks like

csv sample

[image]

Thanks for your help !

Comment: For best results **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("path_to_your_file.csv",header=0)
by_date = data.groupby(["warehouse","date"]).agg(['mean', 'count', 'sum'])
print(by_date)
```

Something like this is simple and would give you your result. You will need to first install pandas library with pip in the console:

```
$>pip install pandas
```

Here you can have some [documentation of the library](https://pandas.pydata.org/) with tutorials and walk-throughs and a [cheatsheet of the basics](https://pandas.pydata.org/Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, but that only gives me statistics by group, I want to plot the data, a line plot with date on the x axis and qty on the y axis, and one plot by group 'warehouse'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot the data rather than simply print it, you can do something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("path_to_your_file.csv")
```

This sho7uld produce a Datafr4ame of the form:

```
    Wharehouse  Date    Qty
0   A        4/20/2022  485
1   A        4/21/2022  642
2   A        4/22/2022  315
3   A        4/23/2022  845
4   B        4/20/2022  325
5   B        4/21/2022  156
6   B        4/22/2022  851
7   C        4/20/2022  268
8   C        4/21/2022  452
9   C        4/22/2022  265
```

To plot the data

```
df.groupby('Wharehouse').plot.bar(x= 'Date', y='Qty')
```

Yields the following:
Wharehouse
A    AxesSubplot(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.755)
B    AxesSubplot(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.755)
C    AxesSubplot(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.755)
dtype: object

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That worked great, thank you so much ! is there a way to add a title to the graph so I know which group it's plotting ? right now there's no way to tell which graph goes with which warehouse.

Comment: Look at docs for dataframe plot to see how to add titles/labels to plots.